# Javascript css class based on random number

Tags: javascript, css

I have a 4x3 matrix where the class is set to blank (white background). I'm using 
`var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*2 + 1);`
and if its 1, the class is set to one (red background) and if its 2, the class is set to two (blue background). My code is suppose to make 6 links red and 6 links blue with the newgame function, however, sometimes a few of them are still white or there are not exactly 6 red or blue. You might need to refresh (not click new game button) to see what I mean

here it is live: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/750932/iPhone/risk.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>RISK</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    a:link, a:visited {color: #eee;border:3px solid #ccc;display:inline-block;margin:3px;text-decoration:none;padding:26px;}
    .blank {background:#fff;}
    .one {background: #7B3B3B;}
    .two {background: #547980;}
    #status {color: #eee;padding:1px;text-align:center}
    .current {border:3px solid #000;}
    p {margin:0 0 15px;padding:0;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var oneTurn = true;
var gameOver = false;
var numMoves = 0;

function newgame()
{
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    var one = 0;
    var two = 0;
    numMoves = 0;
    gameOver = false;
    oneTurn = true;
    status.innerHTML = 'Player One\'s turn';

    for(var x = 0; x < 4; x++)
    {
        for(var y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*2 + 1);
            if(rand == 1 && one < 7)
            {
                document.getElementById('a' + x + '_' + y).setAttribute("class", "one");
                one++;
                console.log("one");
            }
            else if(rand == 2 && two < 7)
            {
                document.getElementById('a' + x + '_' + y).setAttribute("class", "two");
                two++;
                console.log("two");
            }
            document.getElementById('a' + x + '_' + y).innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random()*5 + 1);
        }
    }
    console.log(one);
    console.log(two);
}
function current(selected)
{
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    var value = selected.value; 
}
</script>
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
</head>

<body onload='newgame();'>
<p id="status" class="one">Player One's turn</p>
<br />
<a href="#" id="a0_0" class="blank" onclick="current(this);"></a>
<a href="#" id="a1_0" class="blank" onclick="current(this);"></a>
<a href="#" id="a2_0" class="blank" onclick="current(this);"></a>
<a href="#" id="a3_0" class="blank" onclick="current(this);"></a>
<br />

<a href="#" id="a0_1" class="blank" onclick="current(this);"></a>
<a href="#" id="a1_1" class="blank" onclick="current(this);"></a>
<a href="#" id="a2_1" class="blank" onclick="current(this);"></a>
<a href="#" id="a3_1" class="blank" onclick="current(this);"></a>
<br />

<a href="#" id="a0_2" class="blank" onclick="current(this);"></a>
<a href="#" id="a1_2" class="blank" onclick="current(this);"></a>
<a href="#" id="a2_2" class="blank" onclick="current(this);"></a>
<a href="#" id="a3_2" class="blank" onclick="current(this);"></a>
<br /><br />

<p><input type="button" id="newgame" value="New Game" onclick="newgame();" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me offer you a slightly different approach. Represent the board as an array of 12 integers.

1. Fill the first half of this array with one's and the second half with two's.
2. Shuffle the array
3. Loop through the array and update the DOM elements by converting the array index to the corresponding row and column in the matrix

   ```
   // initialize the array
   var board = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2];

   // shuffle the array
   for(var j, x, i = board.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), 
       x = board[--i], board[i] = board[j], board[j] = x);

   // At this stage one's and two's will be randomly distributed
   var row = -1;
   for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
       var class = board[i] == 1 ? 'one' : 'two';
       var col = i % 4;
       if (col == 0) row++;
       var box = document.getElementById('a' + col + '_' + row);
       if (box != null) {
           box.setAttribute('class', class);
           box.innerHTML = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Read your code again:

```
if(rand == 1 && one < 7)
...
else if(rand == 2 && two < 7)
```

Once you roll a red more than six times, or a blue more than six times, your code just does nothing for that square, this is why you end up with white squares.

Try something like this:

```
if((rand == 1 && one <= 6) || two > 6)
...
else
```

Comment: alright this solved the white square problems. However, sometimes I don't get exactly 6 red and 6 blue.